# Request.Write - execute in Head tag. [Action - Templates]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use BaseUserControl, where I have a method

```
private string typeName
{
    get { return GetType().FullName; }
}

private object headOne
{
    get { return Context.Items[typeName + "_Head"]; }
    set { Context.Items[typeName + "_Head"] = value; }
}

public void Head(Action template)
{
    if (headOne == null)
    {
        template();
        headOne = "exist";
    }
}
```

I use it for now, to not duplicate one user control part. Inside action I have couple Request.Write();

```
<% Head(() => { %>

<style>.css {}</style>

<% }); %>
```

What I am interested, hot to execute this Request in a Head tag. For now I didnot find any way, without creating custom view engine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use masterPages to achieve your purpose . 
But you can also manipulate `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead`
[Here is a sample](http://weblogs.asp.net/pscott/archive/2005/08/30/424039.aspx)